# how to change the icon when have no children in flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, widget, children

[image: Notification Case Senerio]

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.notification);
            },
            icon: ImageIcon(
              Notification == null ? AssetImage("../../images/Icons/bell.png")  : AssetImage("../../images/Icons/bin.png"),
              size: 21,
            ),
          ),
```

*What i wanted is to change the icon whenever any specific widget contains 0 children*

**My Idea is to change the notification icon when we have zero notification and use another icon when notification widget have same children or have some notification**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a list of notification, when length of children was empty,

I suggest to use [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package:

```
  final List _notifications = ['hello'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Badge(
        badgeContent: _notifications.isEmpty
            ? null
            : Text(_notifications.length.toString()),
        child: _notifications.isEmpty
            ? const Icon(Icons.notifications)
            : const Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: result]

now just add items to your List in `StatefulWidget` by setState and do what you like, if you need `IconButton` just pass it in child of your Badge,

read badges doc to fix badgeContent,
good luck

Answer (score 1):

Check out this flutter package

https://pub.dev/packages/badges

It's used to show badges on top of icons